# Is there a way to disable color mixing/overlapping in html canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have a canvas and when i draw 2 things overlapping with low opacity, the opacity gets higher in the part where they are overlapping. Is there a way to make it all the same opacity even if 2 things are overlapping.

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.2)";

ctx.fillRect(10, 10, 50, 50);
ctx.fillRect(20, 20, 50, 60);
ctx.fillRect(40, 5, 50, 40)
```

```css
canvas {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<p>all of it should be the same color but the overlapping parts are darker</p>
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: Presumably you have a reason for the transparency? Like this are on top of something that you want to have show through?

Comment: It's a natural consequence of overlaying items with <1 alpha. Think of it like colored glass panes. When you overlay them, the opacity increases. You might consider a solid color instead. Try a fillStyle of rgb(204, 204, 255) instead.

Answer (score 5):

For simple cases the usual trick is to use a second canvas as a layer: you draw the parts that shouldn't mix with full opacity on a detached canvas, and then you draw this canvas with the intended alpha on the visible one:

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

const detached = canvas.cloneNode();
const ctx2 = detached.getContext("2d");

// draw at full opacity
ctx2.fillStyle = "rgb(0, 0, 255)";

ctx2.fillRect(10, 10, 50, 50);
ctx2.fillRect(20, 20, 50, 60);
ctx2.fillRect(40, 5, 50, 40)

// draw something in the background of the visible canvas
// where we want the blue rects to mix with
ctx.fillStyle = "green";
ctx.fillRect(50, 65, 30, 30);

// now draw the blue rects in a single pass with the expected alpha
ctx.globalAlpha = 0.2
ctx.drawImage(detached, 0, 0);
```

```css
/* CSS checkerboard stolen from https://drafts.csswg.org/css-images-4/#example-2de97f53 */
canvas {
    background: repeating-conic-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.1) 0deg 25%, white 0deg 50%);
    background-size: 2em 2em;
}
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

Note that this exact example could have been done with a single canvas: if all your shape do share the same color, you can make them all be part of the same sub-path and fill them all in a single call.

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

ctx.fillStyle = "green";
ctx.fillRect(50, 65, 30, 30);

ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(0, 0, 255, 0.2)";
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.rect(10, 10, 50, 50);
ctx.rect(20, 20, 50, 60);
ctx.rect(40, 5, 50, 40);
ctx.fill();
```

```css
/* CSS checkerboard stolen from https://drafts.csswg.org/css-images-4/#example-2de97f53 */
canvas {
    background: repeating-conic-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.1) 0deg 25%, white 0deg 50%);
    background-size: 2em 2em;
}
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

Now these work only when the transparency is the same for all the shapes to be drawn. In case of multiple shapes with different alpha values, they'd still get mixed.

Here is an example of such a case.

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

ctx.fillStyle = "green";
ctx.fillRect(50, 10, 50, 60);

ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 0, 255, .2)";
ctx.fillRect(40, 50, 70, 60);

ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 0, 255, .8)";
ctx.fillRect(10, 20, 60, 70);
```

```css
/* CSS checkerboard stolen from https://drafts.csswg.org/css-images-4/#example-2de97f53 */
canvas {
    background: repeating-conic-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.1) 0deg 25%, white 0deg 50%);
    background-size: 2em 2em;
}
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

If we wanted the first blue rect to be over the second one without mixing, but still mix with the green one, we'd need to use a variation of the first solution, but use more steps:

- First you calculate the alpha value of the more transparent rect relative to the more opaque one. Here we have 0.2 and 0.8, so if we want the 0.8 to be 1, 0.2 has to become 0.25.
- We draw the more transparent rect at 0.25, then the more opaque one at 1 over this.
- We redraw the composition with the target 0.8 alpha value.
- We draw that over the green background.

However I'll take the opportunity of this new snippet to show that with some creative use of the [`globalCompositeOperation`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/globalCompositeOperation) property we can make all this on a single canvas.

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

// To use a single canvas, we will draw the green "background" later

// target color is rgb(0, 0, 255, 0.2) & max alpha is 0.8
// 0.2 x (1 / 0.8) -> 0.25
ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(0, 0, 255, 0.25)";
ctx.fillRect(40, 50, 70, 60);
ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 0, 255, 1)";
ctx.fillRect(10, 20, 60, 70);
ctx.globalAlpha = 0.8;
// gCO "copy" will clear whatever was on the context before the next paint
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "copy"; 
ctx.drawImage(ctx.canvas, 0, 0);
// we could continue over like this if more such opacities were required

ctx.globalAlpha = 1;

// gCO "destination-over" will draw behind what's already painted on the context
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-over";
ctx.fillStyle = "green";
ctx.fillRect(50, 10, 50, 60);
```

```css
/* CSS checkerboard stolen from https://drafts.csswg.org/css-images-4/#example-2de97f53 */
canvas {
    background: repeating-conic-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.1) 0deg 25%, white 0deg 50%);
    background-size: 2em 2em;
}
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

---

Now, it may be of interest for some, but at WHATWG/html we started a [discussion about enabling a layer API for the canvas2D](https://github.com/whatwg/html/issues/7329), and while it's far from reaching a consensus, I wrote a not so little [prototype of a CanvasLayer interface](https://github.com/Kaiido/CanvasLayer) that would allow us to, well, use layers in a canvas.

The idea is to create a *CanvasLayer* object, that does record drawings operations that will get executed on it when it's rendered on a context, using the context's current settings. Basically reproducing the detached canvas trick, but with taking care automagically of the sizing of the detached canvas, and (if implemented natively), without assigning a full bitmap buffer.

In my very biased opinion (I'm the author of both *that* proposal and of the prototype), this would allow for clearer code when we have to deal with multiple layers over a canvas.

```css
/* CSS checkerboard stolen from https://drafts.csswg.org/css-images-4/#example-2de97f53 */
canvas {
    background: repeating-conic-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.1) 0deg 25%, white 0deg 50%);
    background-size: 2em 2em;
}
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
<script type="module">
  import CanvasLayer from "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/Kaiido/CanvasLayer/bundles/CanvasLayer.min.mjs";

  const canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
  const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  ctx.fillStyle = "green";
  ctx.fillRect(50, 10, 50, 60);

  const backLayer = new CanvasLayer();
  backLayer.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 0, 255)"; // fully opaque
  backLayer.fillRect(40, 50, 70, 60);
  
  const frontLayer = new CanvasLayer();
  frontLayer.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 0, 255)";
  frontLayer.fillRect(10, 20, 60, 70);
  frontLayer.globalAlpha = 0.2;
  frontLayer.renderLayer(backLayer);

  ctx.globalAlpha = 0.8;
  ctx.renderLayer(frontLayer);
</script>
```